# MailMessage - Error Opening Attachment

Tags: c#, mailmessage, npoi

I am using NPOI to create an excel workbook and attempting to send it as an attachment in an email. My code is as follows:

```
var wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

//create the workbook

using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.Write(ms);
    var msg = new MailMessage();

    //create email

    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Document.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"));

    client.Send(msg);
}
```

I have excluded the code to create the workbook, I have tested to make sure it works (I'm able to save the file and open it without issue) but if you want to see anything please ask. `client` is just my `SmtpClient`.

The email is sent without issue and the attachment is present as Document.xls (as expected), however when I open it I get the following message (in Excel 2010) and when I click 'Yes' to open, the worksheet is blank.

`The file you are trying to open, 'Document.xls', is in a differrent format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?`

To the best of my knowledge I am specifying the format. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried "Document.xlsx" and "application/octet-stream"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Before passing the `Stream` into the `Attachment`, I needed to set its position back to zero.

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

That's it!